# Using two different video cards in the same pc?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I know that I can use two cards together if they are the same model, and I can put them in sli mode. But can I use two cards that are not the same model (Not in sli), I have a geforce 7300gt and a 8600gt. I plugged both in my motherboard but only the first one work, or the second if I unplugg the first, but never both.

How can I have them both working on the same motherboard?

OS: Ubuntu 10.04 using the default driver "Nvidia accelerated graphics driver (version 173)"

Comment: It depends on the operating system and the specific cards in question.  The particular cards in question should work fine together under any operating system; they're using the same driver in all situations, I believe.  The answer might be different for different cards.  You really need to specify your operating system, though, this question is entirely too vague otherwise.

Comment: @Shinrai : Question updated.

Comment: Thank you!  Most new posters don't bother to actually provide useful information when prompted. :/  Unfortunately I have no idea if I'm 100% correct because I'm not a Linux guy, but I believe these should coexist fine.  Hopefully somebody can say for sure.

Answer (score 4):

The long and short is: on most OS (windows[xp|2k|v|7], Linux, etc), yes, as long as your motherboard has enough slots.

I've done this with completely different cards (matrox, ati, nvidia, trident, intel, cirrus, etc) in various linux distros and windows versions.

Linux handles it pretty seamlessly, whether it's different cards from the same vendor, or completely different vendors.  When you boot up it will probably clone your screen.  Head to the system settings menu, then the monitors control panel.  It should be straightforward (the gnome/ubuntu control panels are pretty easy), but search ubuntu's website if you need help.

You said ubuntu, but in case you're dual-booting, windows will be fine with different cards from the same vendor, or different cards from different vendors.  BUT, many people report stability issues with mixing card types in windows.  I never had stability issues under windows (for multiple cards that is;), but I suspect that was because they were work PCs used for business applications, and not 3d games.